# Filtro de extensión archivo

Tags: jquery, vb.net

Estoy trabajando con uploadify v 3.2.1 (con vb.net). Todo bien solo que no me funciona la propiedad para el filtro de la extensión de los archivos de entrada.
Tengo mi código asi:

```
$("[id$='fuArchivoNoticias']").uploadify({

    fileTypeDesc: 'Archivos Excel...', //definir formatos
    fileTypeExts: '*.xlsx; *.xls', // definir formatos de entrada
    fileSizeLimit: '10MB',
    queueSizeLimit: 1,
    auto: false,
    swf: '../Recursos/Js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    uploader: 'Upload_Informaciones.ashx',
    multi: false,
    buttonText: 'Examinar...',
    onSelect: function (obj, varCod, nameFile) {
        $("input[id='hd_nombreArchivo']").val(obj.name);
    },
    onCancel: function (file) {
        console.log("El archivo " + file.name + " fue cancelado.");
    }
});
```

y se me ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigo al pie de la letra la documentación de la página pero no hay caso.

Comment: Ni siquiera el demo de la página muestra el texto aplicado
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypedesc/

Tal vez sea una limitación del plugin

Comment: Puedes subir tu código a algún lugar como plnkr para revisarlo mejor? Lo único que le veo distinto a simple vista es que en la página oficial tiene comillas en ambos lados de lso puntos =>
 'swf': '../Recursos/Js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro luego lo subo, las comillas no son, ya lo probé con las propiedades en comillas y sin comillas.

Comment: depues de mirar esto -> http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypeexts/ busque Google y la primera  que encontre fue esta -> http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/8310/missing-filetypedesc-filetypeexts/p1 creo que puede ayudar Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?¿Qué es lo que está mal en la captura de pantalla?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el filtro de los archivos que acepta el fileupload, donde dice archivos varios, debiesen estar los filtros de Excel que configure.

Comment: @JhonAlx , el texto aplicado en el filtro si lo muestra. (Any old file you want...)

Comment: @AngelAngel, socio si mi ingles no me falla, ahí estan preguntado por la implementación de estas mismas propiedades pero en UploadiFive, no la versión gratuita que trabajo yo como uploadify. corrígeme si me equivoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente el código esta correcto y funciona, lo que no había hecho era probar en otros navegadores, en chrome versión: 47.0.2526.106 m, no funciona y la verdad no sé el porqué, pero en firefox e IE funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]